# specify delimiter in openrowset bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, xml, bulk-insert, openrowset

I'm trying to insert data from CSV files into tables using a cursor and open rowset bulk insert.
this works for me 99% of the times but if one of the fields in the csv files contains a comma( , ) the data import is ruined and all the columns get imported one column after their place.
For example it should look like this:

```
timestamp   username   name         IP       title
20190331    ABCD12G    david hertz  1.1.1.1   null
```

But if i have a comma in the name column(for example) it will look like that:

```
timestamp   username   name      IP      title
20190331    ABCD12G    david    hertz   1.1.1.1
```

the csv example:

```
username,name,ip,title
ABCD12G,david,hertz,1.1.1.1,''
```

This is the syntax i'm using:

```
insert into [player table]
select 20190331,* FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK  'D:\folder\2019\03-
31\Player_statistics.csv', FIRSTROW = 2, 
FORMATFILE='D:\folder\test\xml\Player_statistics.xml')
 as t1
```

how can i change this to ignore the comma in the middle of a word?(i can't limit the CSV since its taken from another client that will not limit characters.

the xml i'm using for the import with openrowset:

[image: xml]

when you perform regular bulk insert you have an option to specify the delimiter
fielterminator = '","'  , I could not find something like that in openrowset.

What can help fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if one of the fields in the csv files contains a comma( , )

If all lines contains a comma, the solution can be

```xml
<ROW>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="username" xsi:type="SQLSMALLINT"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="name1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="name2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="IP" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>  
</ROW>
```

```sql
INSERT INTO [player table]
SELECT 20190331, 
       username, 
       name1+','+name2, 
       IP, 
       title 
FROM  OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\folder\2019\03-31\Player_statistics.csv', 
                  FIRSTROW = 2, 
                  FORMATFILE='D:\folder\test\xml\Player_statistics.xml') t1
```

If only some lines contains commas, and none `title` is null/empty, then try

```sql
INSERT INTO [player table]
SELECT 20190331, 
       `username`, 
       CASE WHEN title IS NULL 
            THEN name1
            ELSE name1+','+name2 END, 
       CASE WHEN title IS NULL 
            THEN name2
            ELSE IP END, 
       CASE WHEN title IS NULL 
            THEN IP
            ELSE title END
       IP, 
       title 
FROM  OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\folder\2019\03-31\Player_statistics.csv', 
                  FIRSTROW = 2, 
                  FORMATFILE='D:\folder\test\xml\Player_statistics.xml') t1
```

If some `title` is null/empty, I cannot find simple way to distinguish.

**UPDATE**

The solution can be: divide your CSV on two fields only - `username` and the whole slack, the slack then can be divided to separate fields using common string functions in the SELECT part of importing query (maybe with using intermediate variables in chain calculations).

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer from below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123875/commas-within-csv-data

We also used to deal with BCP and Transfer however were replacing comma with space(if possible) after agreeing with Client based on the seriousness of column or with .

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i have a few issues: 1. i cant ask the client for anything this is imported from their website as is. 2. this is done on a daily basis and i can;t afford going through csv files and adding ' ' or changing the csv..